# Where is Ascii table is physically located

Tags: memory, architecture, ascii

I take some computer course and the teacher say ASCII table located very far down memory lane. While it looks to me it has to be somewhere pretty close to the CPU since it is transforms chars to hexadecimal machine readable sequences and that you can read letters even when there are no OS.  I found that it is indeed in the BIOS (Basic Input Output System) does anyone can elaborate on physical location of ASCII tables?  is it possible that it would be in a CPU? And how close is it indeed to CPU in Computer Architecture.

If I made any mistake please correct me we're here for learning.

Comment: you need to learn a bit more about computers... any data can be close or far at some point in time(because of the memory hierarchy)

Comment: Is this an attempt at a joke or are you actually asking something?  Because it looks like the former.

Comment: Far down memory lane, means Once upon a time, not deep down in the processor!

Comment: @David He says "If I made any mistake please correct me we're here for learning". So he isn't joking. And there are no stupid questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASCII table is not managed by the BIOS but it's managed by the OS. So it does not have any physical location.

Nowadays they don't necessarily use ASCII, but use UNICODE.

Comment: So how come you have letters when you do not have an OS?

Comment: @sivi, in that case, you're interested in textmode. Read [this Wikipedia article on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mode) for some background. Briefly: video cards implement a non-graphical text mode, and the actual pattern table (what you're calling the "ASCII table") is managed (usually) on the video adapter. The pattern table is what's used to map character points (often ASCII codes) to pixel bitmaps.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Anyways,